# Suppose that $\alpha$ root of the equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

Suppose that $\alpha$ root of this equation: $$x^4+x^2-1=0$$

Find the value of $$\alpha ^{6}+2\alpha ^{4}$$

"I want the way, not the roots of the equation."

I tried, but I couldn't find any thing.

Comment: this problem is little hard, so I couldn't complete my solution

Comment: "Suppose that $\alpha$ root of the equation" is neither a question nor a description of the gist of a question.

Answer (score 5):

HINT :

We have
$$\alpha^4+\alpha^2=1$$and 
$$\alpha^6+\alpha^4=\alpha^2$$

Answer (score 4):

If you do long division $x^6+2x^4 : x^4+x^2-1$ you get a quoatient of $x^2+1$ and a reminder of $1$. Therefore

$$x^6+2x^4=(x^2+1)(x^4+x^2-1)+1$$

Replace now $x=\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You know that $\alpha^4+\alpha^2-1 = 0$. Now, multiply both sides by $\alpha^2+1$ and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha^{4}+\alpha^{2}=1$, multiplying by $\alpha^{2}$, $\alpha^{6}+\alpha^{4}=\alpha^{2}$, so adding $\alpha^{4}$ to both sides, $\alpha^{6}+2\alpha^{4}=\alpha^{2}+\alpha^{4}=1$.